# How to run text related for loop in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I know how to use `For` loops in VBScript to perform arithmetic or any mathematical operations. Could someone explain how to use a `For` loop for strings in VBScript?

Eg:

I have a file called `files_list.txt` which contains a group of text. I am using the following code using `For` loop to print certain text using `If..Else` operation.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim file, filegroup

Set objfile = objFSO.openTextFile("D:\Users\krkarthi\Desktop\files_list.txt")

filegroup = objfile.ReadAll

For Each file In filegroup
    If objFSO.FileExists(file) = True Then
        result = WScript.Echo(Now & " The file &file exists")
    Else 
        result = WScript.Echo(Now & " The file &file do not exists")
    End If
```

As per the above code, I have copied all the files path which I want to monitor in `files_list.txt`. By using the `For` loop I want to check whether a particular file exists or not using the `objFSO.FileExists()` statement. But unfortunately the code is not executable due to some issue. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: *"due to some issue"* being what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `ReadAll` method and then trying to iterate through the returned result line by line. That doesn't work because `ReadAll` returns the entire file content as a single string *(not a string array like what you might be expecting)*.

In order to iterate through the lines of a string, you need to split it first:

```
Dim lines, line
lines = Split(filegroup, vbNewLine)
For Each line In lines
    ' ...
Next
```

That'll work. However, this isn't the best way to iterate through the lines of a text file (especially for large files), let alone having to worry about what kind of [`EOL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character is used.

Fortunately, there's another method called `ReadLine`, which you can use to read one line at a time directly from the text file. In this case, you'll need to use a `Do` loop instead of a `For` loop:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.openTextFile("The\path\to\your\file.txt")

Dim currentLine
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    currentLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If objFSO.FileExists(currentLine) Then
        ' ...
    Else 
        ' ...
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. There is one more thing, post **if** condition, I want to write something like **WScript.echo("The file currentLine exists")**.                 In the above mentioned echo, how can I capture the current Line in echo statement. In otherwords, in the place of CurrentLine, I need to print the exact file name at that time

Comment: @karthik, You can use `WScript.Echo("The file '" & currentLine & "' exists")`.